# SXSSF generated corrupted report in Z/OS on applying cell Style

Tags: java, styles, apache-poi, cell

I am trying to execute a program in Z-OS machine to write an Excel report.
Due to size of the report, we are using SXSSFWorkbook to write the report.

One of the cells in the report is grey in color. So I have to apply Color to that cell.
I used the following code to set the color.

```
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(DatatypeConverter
        .parseHexBinary("FFBFBFBF")); //also tried the java.awt.Color
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

But for the report generated, this cell is dark in color.
Out of curiosity, I checked the Styles.xml inside the Excel document.
The following is what I found.

```
<fill><patternFill patternType="solid"><fgColor rgb="ããâãâãâã"/></patternFill></fill>
```

I tried to generate the same report in a Windows machine, and it gave me correct result.

```
<fill><patternFill patternType="solid"><fgColor rgb="FFBFBFBF"/></patternFill>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

----------------------**EDITED**---------------------------

I have reported a bug for this.
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56683

To debug this, i need to see the code for CT classes in POI.
I followed the instructions given in following link to generate the code.
http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1012A

1) I am not able to find ' ooxml-schemas-src jar'.
2) I checkedout POI code and ANT build it.

None of the approch gave me the code for CT classes.
let me know if someone have done it before.

**---------------EDITED----------------------------**

Not sure if the following update will fix it. need to try it out.

Updated writeTo() method of 'org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable'.

Change: Added the following line

```
         'DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");'


/**
 * Write this table out as XML.
 *
 * @param out The stream to write to.
 * @throws IOException if an error occurs while writing.
 */
public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    //Setting default encoding to UTF-8
    DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    XmlOptions options = new XmlOptions(DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS);
```

Since i dont have control over the z/os server, i have to wait till it get tested.
In the mean time, please let me know your thoughts on the same.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use XSSF? (Maybe skip some rows when testing). And are you using the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: I haven't tested it using XSSF. I'll try to do it and update. Yes, I am using the apache poi version 3.10 FINAL. I faced another issue while writing the report, but fortunately there was a patch for it. https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55594. https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=31421.   Need to understand, how apache poi writes the Styles.xml. Please let me know if you have any clue on this.

Comment: Apache POI is open source, so you can just look at the code yourself if need be!

Comment: If you build POI from source, by running "ant jar", the ooxml src jar should end up in the `ooxml-lib` folder - did you try checking there?

Comment: I noticed the following when i Ant Build the source code
"[echo]   This is POI 3.11-beta1"
I took the source code from 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf' --> poi --> trunk. Where in SVN, i can find the source for 3.10 Final. I am going behind repository as i dont know how to setup the Souce provided as ZIP, in eclipse.

Comment: ooxml src jar is not generated on doing Ant Build.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with maven / Ant.All i know is that i have to run build.xml.

Comment: You need to run "ant jar" to generate all the jars, the default ant target just prints the build help

Comment: I am able to generate the source files now. Mean time, i tried to do a work around by writing the Styles using XSSFWorkbook and use those styles while writing with SXSSFWorkbook. That too failed. Need to deebug and find which class is resposible for writing the styles. If you have any clue plz let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now.

Please see the bug page for details.
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56683